# How to describe the derivative of matlab symbolic variable？

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

For example, I named the variables x(t), xdot(t) about time: `syms t x(t) xdot(t);`, and the derivative of x about time is xdot, `xdot=diff(x,t)`.
But when I calculate diff (x, t), the result is not xdot. How can I set the display of diff (x, t) in the calculation result to xdot?
In addition, the time variable in the calculation result is displayed in the form of `variable(t)`. How to set the result to display only `variable`?

```matlab
syms t x(t) xdot(t);
xdot=diff(x,t);
y=diff(x,t);
y
```

the result of `y` is displayed as  [image], however, I want it to be `xdot`

Comment: Shows us the code, its not entirely clear (to me) what you mean

Comment: As Ander mentioned, it is hard to provide a great answer.

Consider,
assignin('base', 'xdot', simplify(diff(x, t)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
a = 3;
b = 3;
b
```

It appears to me, you would like this to display `b = a`, instead of `b = 3`. This is not how MATLAB works. Both `a` and `b` are equal to `3`, but that doesn't mean `a` is `b`.

The same is true for the code:

```
a = 3;
b = a;
b
```

This gives `b = 3`, not `b = a`. I won't go into details about *why* this is the case (and why it has to be the case in MATLAB). It's enough to know that this is how it works.

You have assigned `diff(x,t)` to two *different* variables, `xdot` and `y`. This means that, while `xdot` and `y` have the same value, `xdot` *is not* `y`.

If you do `xdot = 3` after your code, then `y` would still be dx/dt.

Side note: Why do you want this behaviour? Are you sure it's necessary? You can always print the result however you like:

```
fprintf('xdot = %s', y(t))
xdot = diff(x(t), t)
```

---

Ugly workaround to do something I don't understand why you would do:

Create a function:

```
function res = xdot(t)
   syms x(t) res;
   res = diff(x,t);
end
```

And then define `y` as a function handle:

```
y = @xdot
y = function_handle with value:
  @xdot
```

Now `y(t)` will still give `dx/dt`, but `y` will give `xdot`

I strongly recommend you don't do this.

Comment: I want to do this for the reason that I want to use these symbolic variables to deduce the formula, not calculate the result, like this:. And I don't know other tools for deriving formulas besides the symbol toolbox.